# C# release directory remains empty

Tags: c#

I have an C# application. I can debug the application and Visual Studio C# writes de debug files to bin/debug.

When I use "Built Solution" to compile the application, C# shows no errors and says "Build succeeded"... but the bin/release directory remains empty.

All other applications I compile don't have this problem.

Where did my compiled application go to?

Comment: You didn't say "I switched to the Release configuration".

Comment: @Hans, what is the "Release configuration"? I don't need it. When I create a new application, it doesn't have these configuration settings either.

Answer (score 4):

Set your compilation to `Release` in the configuration manager.

[image]

Comment: "Active solution configuration: Release" is set to "Configuration: Release" and "Active solution configuration: Debug" is set to "Configuration: Debug".

Comment: When I set Debug to Release, it works though (files show up in bin/release).

Comment: So that fixed your problem? You can create new configuration types, mine is just the default for VS2010.

Comment: @Dustin, no not really, I think VS is copying the debug version, since there is a vshost file.

Comment: @Dustin, can I turn it this configuration off and revert back to the default settings? When I create a new application, I dont have these settings.

Comment: You can add/edit/remove configurations at will. Look at the config manager.

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps a silly question, but have you selected the Release configuration when building your solution?

Comment: "Active solution configuration: Release" is set to "Configuration: Release" and "Active solution configuration: Debug" is set to "Configuration: Debug"